# PHP time() and .htaccess %{TIME} difference

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, time

I am using PHP to auto-generate an .htaccess file, and I need to be able to output the time for a `RewriteCond` statement. I'm able to do this, but there appears to be a 5-hour difference between .htaccess `%{TIME}` and PHP `time()`. So if I use PHP to generate the following:

```
$time = time();     // Get the current time
$time = $time + 30; // Add 30 seconds
$expires = date("YmdHis", $time); // Convert to .htaccess time format

$htaccess_contents = "RewriteEngine on" . PHP_EOL; 
$htaccess_contents .= "RewriteCond %{TIME} >$expires" . PHP_EOL; // Check time
$htaccess_contents .= "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com/" // Redirect

file_put_contents( $htaccess_path, $htaccess_contents ); // Overwrite .htaccess
```

The above doesn't work because the time that PHP outputs is 5 hours ahead of what .htaccess thinks the time is. I would prefer not to hardcode in the 5 hour difference. Is it possible to output the time so that times in PHP and .htaccess will be the same?

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue.

Comment: I don't think you have a choice but to hard code it, it would seem the timezone is set differently in the PHP config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` doesn't "think" anything about the time. You should check system time, e.g. the output of `date` on a *nix system and compare it with PHP's `time()`. Difference probably comes from PHP's time zone configuration. Check PHP time zone with `date_default_timezone_get`. If you have no control over PHP's ini configuration, use `date_default_timezone_set` at runtime.

Comment: I paired `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York')` in my PHP file with `SetEnv TZ America/New_York` in my .htaccess for good measure. Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your PHP is set in `php.ini` to use a specific timezone other than what the server is set to.  Find your server's timezone (Linux use `date`) and use [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) in your script.